# How to Convert .class files to . java files

Tags: java, decompiler

I have jar file, when i was extract this i got multiple .class files. I need to convert all .class files to .java files.

Now, Im using **"cavaj"**  decompiler. But it's converting only one file at a time.

Im expecting **convert all** *.class* files to *.java* files.

Appreciate if some any one can help me to find the solution. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How are you using cavaj (what command)?

Answer (score 2):

I use **jadclipse** decompiler in my Eclipse. And so far i have found it great.

This tool (**jad**) also provides option to de-compile from command line. So you should be able to decompile jar or multiple .class files.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another java de-compiler. It's converting multiple .class files to .java Files.

Here is the link java [De-Compiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)